# JDBC URL with ignorecase is not working for H2 database connection

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I was trying to use h2 database in SQL mode. I was able to create a schema, all upper case, and create some tables under it. However, my application running on hibernate does not seem to work unless I match the schema name in all upper cases. I thought h2 could be configured using IGNROECASE=TRUE in the JDBC connection string. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is that a type?Should be IGNORECASE=TRUE

Comment: will this help: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/1e2710f347bb872bda3f0f5ce9e1a865b8050ffb/src/main/resources/application.properties#L9-L23

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IGNORECASE` setting is not related with names of database objects, it changes collation of `CHARACTER VARYING` columns to case insensitive in the weird way.

Unquoted identifiers in H2 with default settings and in many other DBMS are converted to upper case as required by the SQL Standard.

If you use MySQL or PostgreSQL compatibility modes, you usually need to specify `DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE`, because these DBMS convert unquoted identifiers to lower case instead. You can find more detail about these compatibility modes there:
https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

In some cases you may also need `CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE`.

Both these settings are available since H2 1.4.198. In older versions you can use `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` instead; but don't use this setting in newer versions.

Comment: My URL already has those properties. I am using 1.4.200. Is this correct?
jdbc:h2:file:../../../test-classes/test4;MODE=MSSQLServer;database_to_upper=false;IGNORECASE=true;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;

Comment: You need to remove `DATBASE_TO_UPPER` setting with its value.

Comment: I changed to the following but still getting exception jdbc:h2:file:${project.build.directory}/test-classes/test4;MODE=MSSQLServer;IGNORECASE=true;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "my_schema" not found;

Comment: If you're sure that this schema exists, but with different case of characters in its name, you can add `CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE` setting. But it means a some problem in your application.

Comment: Removed DATABASE_TO_UPPER and added CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE resolved the issue. Thank you all.