# Could you offer some tips on configuring CASE_IGNORING to an embedded H2 database?

Tags: java, spring, h2, mybatis

I am using spring, mybatis plus, and unit test with @MybatisPlusTest annotation.

I believe that @MybatisPlusTest will assist me in building an embedded database server.

Here are the logs relating to the database when the spring container starts.

```
2023-06-08 10:36:02.187  INFO 1911 --- [           main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2023-06-08 10:36:02.749  INFO 1911 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:e9cde56b-3395-44fb-8251-c79b0b36e653;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

here is schema-h2.sql

```
create table if not exists person
(
    id   int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    age  int         not null
);
```

here is the PersonMapper

```
@Repository
public interface PersonMapper extends BaseMapper<Person> {
    @Select("select name, age from person")
    public List<Map<String, Object>> selectCertainColumns();
}
```

After I call `personMapper.selectCertainColumns()`, I get a `List<Map<String, Object>> rows`, and I want to get value of column `name`:

#### Expected:

rows.get(0).get("name")

#### Actual:

rows.get(0).get("NAME")

from [JDBC URL with ignorecase is not working for H2 database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66871730/16702058), I understand that I should change the h2 datasource bean's url as follows:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:xxxx;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
```

#### Problem is:

**I am unable to modify the configuration or url used to build the embedded H2 database.**

Could you offer some tips on setting up an embedded H2 database?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by creating a custom configuration for test to overrides the default configuration provided by @MybatisPlusTest. You can create a new configuration and annotate it with @TestConfiguration. Then you can define a bean for the embedded H2 database and set its JDBC URL with the required parameters.

for example I defined a bean for the embedded H2 database and set its JDBC URL with the required parameters: `CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE`

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MybatisSqlSessionFactoryBean mybatisSqlSessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {
        MybatisSqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new MybatisSqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration = new org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration();
        configuration.setMapUnderscoreToCamelCase(true);

        sessionFactory.setConfiguration(configuration);

        Resource[] mapperLocations = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
                .getResources("classpath:mapper/*.xml");

        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(mapperLocations);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-h2.sql"));

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);

        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration = new org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration();
        configuration.setMapUnderscoreToCamelCase(true);

        sessionFactory.setConfiguration(configuration);

        Resource[] mapperLocations = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
                .getResources("classpath:mapper/*.xml");

        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(mapperLocations);
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

Afterward to use custom configuration in your tests, annotate your test class with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)`.

I hope it solve the problem

Comment: I change datasource like you said, to a customed h2 databases, url like `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false;` and it worked, thanks a lot, I think I know how to deal with embedded database now

Comment: Another thing is I have to put `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` on top of my test class, to prevent the embedded database being activated